# How to check JS Webauthn Assertion in PHP 8.1?

Tags: javascript, php, openssl, assertion, webauthn

I'm trying to implement [WebAuthn](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#sctn-intro) in a JavaScript/PHP project and I'm "stuck" at the final assertion verification process.

**In detail, I pass the "assertion" parameters from JavaScript (Jquery) to PHP script like this:**

```
navigator.credentials.get( { publicKey: {
    allowCredentials:   [...],
    challenge:      Uint8Array.from( ..., c => c.charCodeAt( 0 ) ),
    rpId:           window.location.hostname,
    timeout:        60000,
    userVerification:   'preferred'
} } )
.then( ( assertion ) => {
    $.ajax( { data: 'login=' + encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify( {
        ...,
        'rawid':        new Uint8Array( assertion.rawId ),
        'authenticatordata':    new Uint8Array( assertion.response.authenticatorData ),
        'clientdatajson':   new Uint8Array( assertion.response.clientDataJSON ),
        'signature':        new Uint8Array( assertion.response.signature )
    } ) ) } )
```

**And once the "public key" corresponding to the authenticator employed by the user has been identified within a database, I try to validate in PHP 8.1 the "assertion" in this way:**

```
    $jsonInput = json_decode( '{"authenticatordata":{"0":201,"1":157,"2":215,"3":147,"4":42,"5":142,"6":165,"7":93,"8":198,"9":108,"10":247,"11":140,"12":253,"13":224,"14":178,"15":122,"16":185,"17":204,"18":239,"19":151,"20":3,"21":24,"22":2,"23":25,"24":212,"25":39,"26":42,"27":95,"28":255,"29":195,"30":201,"31":113,"32":5,"33":0,"34":0,"35":0,"36":16},"clientdatajson":{"0":123,"1":34,"2":116,"3":121,"4":112,"5":101,"6":34,"7":58,"8":34,"9":119,"10":101,"11":98,"12":97,"13":117,"14":116,"15":104,"16":110,"17":46,"18":103,"19":101,"20":116,"21":34,"22":44,"23":34,"24":99,"25":104,"26":97,"27":108,"28":108,"29":101,"30":110,"31":103,"32":101,"33":34,"34":58,"35":34,"36":77,"37":68,"38":65,"39":119,"40":77,"41":68,"42":65,"43":119,"44":77,"45":68,"46":65,"47":119,"48":77,"49":103,"50":34,"51":44,"52":34,"53":111,"54":114,"55":105,"56":103,"57":105,"58":110,"59":34,"60":58,"61":34,"62":104,"63":116,"64":116,"65":112,"66":115,"67":58,"68":47,"69":47,"70":109,"71":111,"72":114,"73":109,"74":105,"75":110,"76":111,"77":46,"78":114,"79":101,"80":115,"81":105,"82":101,"83":108,"84":46,"85":99,"86":111,"87":109,"88":34,"89":44,"90":34,"91":99,"92":114,"93":111,"94":115,"95":115,"96":79,"97":114,"98":105,"99":103,"100":105,"101":110,"102":34,"103":58,"104":102,"105":97,"106":108,"107":115,"108":101,"109":125},"signature":{"0":48,"1":69,"2":2,"3":33,"4":0,"5":251,"6":22,"7":162,"8":18,"9":206,"10":81,"11":110,"12":4,"13":3,"14":217,"15":148,"16":51,"17":132,"18":130,"19":31,"20":122,"21":186,"22":65,"23":73,"24":195,"25":170,"26":106,"27":35,"28":90,"29":149,"30":56,"31":1,"32":58,"33":222,"34":51,"35":69,"36":212,"37":2,"38":32,"39":77,"40":161,"41":139,"42":133,"43":49,"44":79,"45":218,"46":34,"47":45,"48":115,"49":178,"50":156,"51":139,"52":185,"53":13,"54":197,"55":248,"56":116,"57":217,"58":81,"59":111,"60":117,"61":68,"62":44,"63":141,"64":197,"65":87,"66":68,"67":1,"68":89,"69":222,"70":154}}' );
    $publickey = json_decode( '{"0":48,"1":89,"2":48,"3":19,"4":6,"5":7,"6":42,"7":134,"8":72,"9":206,"10":61,"11":2,"12":1,"13":6,"14":8,"15":42,"16":134,"17":72,"18":206,"19":61,"20":3,"21":1,"22":7,"23":3,"24":66,"25":0,"26":4,"27":229,"28":126,"29":127,"30":191,"31":207,"32":67,"33":42,"34":66,"35":212,"36":251,"37":1,"38":126,"39":36,"40":232,"41":163,"42":188,"43":151,"44":84,"45":50,"46":83,"47":251,"48":29,"49":196,"50":24,"51":208,"52":131,"53":96,"54":190,"55":14,"56":239,"57":104,"58":123,"59":78,"60":90,"61":70,"62":76,"63":54,"64":211,"65":91,"66":74,"67":243,"68":252,"69":69,"70":192,"71":132,"72":245,"73":206,"74":214,"75":67,"76":210,"77":165,"78":46,"79":230,"80":191,"81":6,"82":19,"83":241,"84":201,"85":188,"86":235,"87":232,"88":84,"89":130,"90":185}', TRUE );
    $jsonInput->authenticatordata = ( array ) $jsonInput->authenticatordata;    // [201,157,215,147,42,142,165,93,198,108,247,140,253,224,178,122,185,204,239,151,3,24,2,25,212,39,42,95,255,195,201,113,5,0,0,0,16]
    $jsonInput->clientdatajson = ( array ) $jsonInput->clientdatajson;      // [123,34,116,121,112,101,34,58,34,119,101,98,97,117,116,104,110,46,103,101,116,34,44,34,99,104,97,108,108,101,110,103,101,34,58,34,77,68,65,119,77,68,65,119,77,68,65,119,77,103,34,44,34,111,114,105,103,105,110,34,58,34,104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,109,111,114,109,105,110,111,46,114,101,115,105,101,108,46,99,111,109,34,44,34,99,114,111,115,115,79,114,105,103,105,110,34,58,102,97,108,115,101,125]
    $jsonInput->signature = ( array ) $jsonInput->signature;            // [48,69,2,33,0,251,22,162,18,206,81,110,4,3,217,148,51,132,130,31,122,186,65,73,195,170,106,35,90,149,56,1,58,222,51,69,212,2,32,77,161,139,133,49,79,218,34,45,115,178,156,139,185,13,197,248,116,217,81,111,117,68,44,141,197,87,68,1,89,222,154]

    echo openssl_verify(
        implode( array_map( 'chr', $jsonInput->authenticatordata ) ) . hash( 'sha256', json_encode( implode( array_map( 'chr', $jsonInput->clientdatajson ) ) ) ),
        implode( array_map( 'chr', $jsonInput->signature ) ),
        "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n" . chunk_split( base64_encode( implode( array_map( 'chr', $publickey ) ) ), 64 ) . "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",
        OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256
    );
    echo '<br />';
    echo openssl_error_string(); // error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error

/*The processed Windows Hello (From Windows 11) authenticator-generated public key results at the end:

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE5X5/v89DKkLU+wF+JOijvJdUMlP7
HcQY0INgvg7vaHtOWkZMNtNbSvP8RcCE9c7WQ9KlLua/BhPxybzr6FSCuQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

*/
```

**Another example with a different authenticator (Widows Hello from Windows 10):**

```
    $jsonInput                      = json_decode( '{"authenticatordata":[201,157,215,147,42,142,165,93,198,108,247,140,253,224,178,122,185,204,239,151,3,24,2,25,212,39,42,95,255,195,201,113,5,0,0,0,2],"clientdatajson":[123,34,116,121,112,101,34,58,34,119,101,98,97,117,116,104,110,46,103,101,116,34,44,34,99,104,97,108,108,101,110,103,101,34,58,34,77,68,65,119,77,68,65,119,77,68,65,119,77,103,34,44,34,111,114,105,103,105,110,34,58,34,104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,109,111,114,109,105,110,111,46,114,101,115,105,101,108,46,99,111,109,34,44,34,99,114,111,115,115,79,114,105,103,105,110,34,58,102,97,108,115,101,44,34,111,116,104,101,114,95,107,101,121,115,95,99,97,110,95,98,101,95,97,100,100,101,100,95,104,101,114,101,34,58,34,100,111,32,110,111,116,32,99,111,109,112,97,114,101,32,99,108,105,101,110,116,68,97,116,97,74,83,79,78,32,97,103,97,105,110,115,116,32,97,32,116,101,109,112,108,97,116,101,46,32,83,101,101,32,104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,103,111,111,46,103,108,47,121,97,98,80,101,120,34,125],"signature":[94,96,8,15,78,8,75,244,177,242,61,244,7,240,100,98,176,74,243,176,215,209,229,61,5,137,178,77,240,88,160,220,9,110,33,171,52,255,65,140,191,209,29,49,26,111,164,65,47,1,90,77,95,196,60,132,185,189,145,0,138,65,212,242,210,222,55,91,211,208,15,216,252,81,6,132,159,42,234,186,78,81,121,187,45,71,22,178,83,210,196,161,31,247,188,218,211,159,5,102,249,213,142,158,230,99,182,166,78,62,153,107,53,133,150,96,95,99,213,172,19,44,243,114,127,167,155,195,88,172,236,229,233,212,65,100,127,98,4,4,71,124,29,174,104,65,190,218,221,16,228,85,137,216,250,89,49,77,245,120,146,72,7,23,67,144,108,160,195,204,216,51,100,159,32,208,151,249,87,146,54,31,230,48,241,67,235,8,171,198,53,8,83,178,8,203,6,173,76,213,212,128,241,72,129,162,159,13,234,49,6,140,253,159,107,115,91,151,195,25,203,27,98,81,41,96,254,88,92,126,78,207,59,114,214,238,153,34,100,49,59,246,249,99,255,49,71,178,42,226,62,246,149,193,91,140]}' );
    $publickey                      = json_decode( '{"0":48,"1":130,"2":1,"3":34,"4":48,"5":13,"6":6,"7":9,"8":42,"9":134,"10":72,"11":134,"12":247,"13":13,"14":1,"15":1,"16":1,"17":5,"18":0,"19":3,"20":130,"21":1,"22":15,"23":0,"24":48,"25":130,"26":1,"27":10,"28":2,"29":130,"30":1,"31":1,"32":0,"33":226,"34":31,"35":139,"36":141,"37":197,"38":58,"39":76,"40":61,"41":52,"42":104,"43":160,"44":127,"45":66,"46":27,"47":61,"48":3,"49":107,"50":228,"51":250,"52":6,"53":98,"54":104,"55":214,"56":5,"57":33,"58":182,"59":247,"60":175,"61":107,"62":236,"63":71,"64":232,"65":98,"66":163,"67":112,"68":213,"69":174,"70":56,"71":131,"72":160,"73":93,"74":200,"75":85,"76":35,"77":234,"78":116,"79":212,"80":172,"81":0,"82":232,"83":78,"84":48,"85":90,"86":122,"87":93,"88":100,"89":212,"90":88,"91":250,"92":91,"93":228,"94":248,"95":14,"96":42,"97":228,"98":123,"99":149,"100":36,"101":205,"102":21,"103":172,"104":116,"105":44,"106":113,"107":229,"108":246,"109":50,"110":110,"111":219,"112":122,"113":219,"114":26,"115":72,"116":17,"117":120,"118":63,"119":148,"120":176,"121":94,"122":110,"123":133,"124":131,"125":199,"126":213,"127":219,"128":22,"129":29,"130":88,"131":178,"132":141,"133":62,"134":170,"135":76,"136":121,"137":62,"138":237,"139":192,"140":214,"141":82,"142":122,"143":113,"144":244,"145":124,"146":2,"147":5,"148":39,"149":83,"150":68,"151":252,"152":219,"153":233,"154":27,"155":128,"156":77,"157":160,"158":241,"159":92,"160":1,"161":0,"162":171,"163":214,"164":233,"165":178,"166":240,"167":207,"168":227,"169":74,"170":134,"171":206,"172":217,"173":193,"174":89,"175":79,"176":56,"177":217,"178":152,"179":229,"180":175,"181":47,"182":146,"183":145,"184":101,"185":173,"186":39,"187":106,"188":252,"189":194,"190":107,"191":221,"192":150,"193":30,"194":122,"195":73,"196":204,"197":49,"198":242,"199":60,"200":227,"201":208,"202":10,"203":223,"204":182,"205":195,"206":105,"207":113,"208":99,"209":119,"210":41,"211":215,"212":234,"213":227,"214":166,"215":69,"216":66,"217":160,"218":83,"219":131,"220":109,"221":111,"222":216,"223":9,"224":55,"225":176,"226":107,"227":4,"228":108,"229":37,"230":235,"231":100,"232":88,"233":14,"234":154,"235":247,"236":143,"237":102,"238":106,"239":48,"240":200,"241":8,"242":152,"243":187,"244":73,"245":126,"246":95,"247":139,"248":83,"249":140,"250":199,"251":151,"252":46,"253":174,"254":25,"255":82,"256":240,"257":199,"258":41,"259":126,"260":106,"261":126,"262":93,"263":201,"264":70,"265":217,"266":151,"267":46,"268":117,"269":139,"270":144,"271":29,"272":43,"273":76,"274":59,"275":180,"276":255,"277":208,"278":43,"279":124,"280":111,"281":168,"282":50,"283":221,"284":105,"285":134,"286":153,"287":113,"288":141,"289":2,"290":3,"291":1,"292":0,"293":1}', TRUE );
    $jsonInput->authenticatordata   = ( array ) $jsonInput->authenticatordata;
    $jsonInput->clientdatajson      = ( array ) $jsonInput->clientdatajson;
    $jsonInput->signature           = ( array ) $jsonInput->signature;

    echo openssl_verify(
        implode( array_map( 'chr', $jsonInput->authenticatordata ) ) . hash( 'sha256', implode( array_map( 'chr', $jsonInput->clientdatajson ) ) ),
        implode( array_map( 'chr', $jsonInput->signature ) ),
        "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n" . chunk_split( base64_encode( implode( array_map( 'chr', $publickey ) ) ), 64 ) . "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",
        OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256
    );
    echo '<br />';
    echo openssl_error_string(); // error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag

    /*
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4h+LjcU6TD00aKB/Qhs9
    A2vk+gZiaNYFIbb3r2vsR+hio3DVrjiDoF3IVSPqdNSsAOhOMFp6XWTUWPpb5PgO
    KuR7lSTNFax0LHHl9jJu23rbGkgReD+UsF5uhYPH1dsWHViyjT6qTHk+7cDWUnpx
    9HwCBSdTRPzb6RuATaDxXAEAq9bpsvDP40qGztnBWU842Zjlry+SkWWtJ2r8wmvd
    lh56Scwx8jzj0ArftsNpcWN3Kdfq46ZFQqBTg21v2Ak3sGsEbCXrZFgOmvePZmow
    yAiYu0l+X4tTjMeXLq4ZUvDHKX5qfl3JRtmXLnWLkB0rTDu0/9ArfG+oMt1phplx
    jQIDAQAB
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    */
```

**1. However the "openssl_verify" function returns failure (0) instead
of success (1). Where am I wrong?**

**2. Why does Windows Hello return a short public key in the first case?
Is it equally valid?**

**3. Is this the correct way to convert to PEM and use the public key
generated by [credential.response.getPublicKey()](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#dom-authenticatorattestationresponse-getpublickey)?**

**Note: in a different context, I transfer the public key from javascript (jquery) to PHP 8.1 like this:**

```
    navigator.credentials.create( { publicKey: {
        attestation:            'none',
        authenticatorSelection: { userVerification: 'preferred' },
        challenge:              Uint8Array.from( ..., c => c.charCodeAt( 0 ) ),
        excludeCredentials:     [],
        pubKeyCredParams:       [],
        rp:                     { id: window.location.hostname, name: window.document.title },
        timeout:                60000,
        user:                   { id: Uint8Array.from( ..., c => c.charCodeAt( 0 ) ), displayName: ..., name: ... }
    } } )
    .then( ( credential ) => {
        $.ajax( { data: 'data=' + encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify( {
            ...,
            'publickey':            new Uint8Array( credential.response.getPublicKey() ),
            'authenticatordata':    new Uint8Array( credential.response.getAuthenticatorData() ),
            'transports':           credential.response.getTransports()
        } ) ) } )
```

Comment: implode( array_map( 'chr', $jsonInput->clientdatajson ) ) is already a string. I don't think you have to json encoded it. But that seems that it is not the only problem

Comment: with adding at the end echo openssl_error_string(); the error is "error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line". You have a problem with your public key.

Comment: The hashedClientDataJson must be binary -> hash('sha256", $clientDataJson, true);

Comment: The doc : https://webauthn.guide/ indicate that the pubKey is encoded with COSE. You have to decode it with a CBOR library. But other actions have to be made after. Take a look to this project https://github.com/lbuchs/WebAuthn

Comment: In the meantime, thank you for your help. The webauthn.guide is outdated. Later, to simplify the decoding of the parameters, they introduced the methods getPublicKey(), getAuthenticatorData() and getTransports() (here the discussion that led to the change: https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1683 )

Comment: The hashedClientDataJson must be binary -> hash('sha256", $clientDataJson, true);

This seems to fix the problem. In both example cases the validation is successful, even though I get the warning: "error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line".
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: good news, and you're welcome